# Maven Jar Plugin and Maven Source Plugin Usage

Tags: java, maven

I know how to use jar plugin and source plugin. I want to use my jar libray with source code and compiled code. How can I do this ? I am confused because there are two jar file created. How can I use these files with another project ? Just adding dependencies or there is a more convenient way ? I do not know. Thank you..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you've set up the`artifactId`, `groupId` and `version` on your project, and done a `mvn install` on it, it should be available on your local repo so you can later import it to the other project with the `<dependecy/>` tag.